# jQuery post data to webapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, asp.net-web-api

My question is two-fold: 1. When sending data from client to my webapi controller, do the names have to be the same?

If I have my model like this:

```
public class Donation
{
    public string DonorType { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

But my form on my webpage is like this:

```
<div class="button-group grid-x align-center" id='sz-gift-source-group'>
    <a class="hollow button cell small-6" id="sz-donate-individual" sz-data-toggle-button required>A family or individual</a>
    <a class="hollow button cell small-6" id="sz-donate-corporate" sz-data-toggle-button>A business or company</a>
</div>
```

With my event handler like this:

```
$('form button[type=submit]').on('click', () => {
    const donation = getDonation();

    $.post(
        '//localhost:61012/api/Donation',
        $("#sz-donate-form").serialize(),
        (data) => {
            console.log(`post succeeded:[${JSON.stringify(data)}]`); 
        })
        .fail((data) => {
            console.log(`post failed:[${JSON.stringify(data)}]`);
        })
        .always((data) => {
            console.log(`post complete:[${JSON.stringify(data)}]`);
        });

    return false;
});
```

And secondly, what do I need to do to get the data from the form to the Donation object?

The tutorials I've looked at all seem to miss my first question, and part of what I'm wondering is if I've got an incomplete form here...

Comment: Note that `serialize()` retrieves data from inputs within a `form` element. If you're expecting the `text()`, or any other attribute of the `a` elements you've shown, to be sent in the request, that's not going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you must for serialize data's a form put your **inputs** inside **form** tag such as :

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="sz-donate-form">
    <input name="DonorType" type="text">
</form>
```

> Note when you use `serialize()` form data serialized by inputs name
>   attribute!

The name attribute should be same with `Donation` class `property`.

I think that you used *typescript*.

Your javascript code should be right.

Please post your action code in webapi to guid for it.

Comment: This isn't the answer, exactly, but it lead me down the right path - basically, it _looks_ like a form input, but these elements aren't set up as any kind of input anywhere...separately, the answer of "The name attribute should be the same" as the Donation class property is what I was looking for...